# How to insert values of set container in a map container in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I have a file in the following format.

```
47304 -  305,463,190,444,  4, 97, 41,381,414,459,159, 75,  5,207,....
50854 -   498,214,300,274,392,390,262, 28,231,349,251, 30,254, 51,326, ..
.
.
```

I wish to use a map container with set as values.

Hence I want to create a map container with key as value present before '-' (ie 47304) and its value must be a set containing the values present after the '-' (ie. 305, 463, 444 etc)

Likewise I want to repeat the same with the other lines of that file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you have a problem show your effort, code and errors

Comment: What have you thought about, what you are going to use as a key ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code-writing service.

Comment: Hints: use `if (std::ifstream file_stream(filename)) { ...use file...} else std::cerr << "unable to open file\n";` to open the file, use `std::string line; while (getline(file_stream, line)) ...` to read the file into lines, use `std::istringstream iss(line); int n; while (iss >> n) { ...use n...; if (iss >> c && c != ',') { std::cerr << "invalid char\n"; exit(1); } }`.

Answer (score 0):

There are really many many potential solutions for that.

Often the `std::getline` [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with delimiter is used, to read up to the dash or to the comma. Also regex, in conjunction with the `std::sregex_token_iterator` will produce very powerfull solutions (although a little bit slow).

But in this case, we can also use a more simple solution.

First, we read a complete line. This gives us a little bit security in case of some incorrectly formatted data. This line will be put into a `std::istringstream`, so that we can simply extract data from there with normal `>>` operations.

To eat up the dash '-' and the commas ',', we will use a dummy-throw-away variable and alwys read a pair of character and number.

`iss >> iss >>  dummyChar >> value` will always read a dash/comma and a value,

This makes then life very simple.

We can then do for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

std::istringstream fileSimulationStream{R"(47304 -  305,463,190,444,  4, 97, 41,381,414,459,159, 75,  5,207
50854 -   498,214,300,274,392,390,262, 28,231,349,251, 30,254, 51,326)"};

int main() {
    
    // Resulting data
    std::map<int,std::set<int>> data;
    
    // Read all lines from file
    for (std::string line{}; std::getline(fileSimulationStream, line); ) {
        
        // Put line in an istringstream for further extraction
        std::istringstream iss{line};
        
        // Get the key for the map
        int key{}; iss>> key;
        
        // Read the rest of the values in a temporary set
        std::set<int> tempSet{}; char dummyChar{}; int value{};
        while (iss >>  dummyChar >> value) tempSet.insert(value);
        
        // Now add everything to the map
        data[key] = std::move(tempSet);
    }
    // Create some debug output
    for (const auto&[key, set] : data) {
        std::cout << key << "\t--> ";
        for (const int i : set) std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```